# Why does StackOverflow make you wait 2-x minutes before you can accept an answer?

Tags: discussion, support, accepted-answer, up-votes

Hi,

It is kind of an annoying feature that I have to wait to accept an answer after I upvote it.  Why is it done like that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It wants you not to rush to pick an answer that soon. Much better answers could be posted after that.

Comment: Ok - I can accept your answer in 8 minutes :) ...lol..really :) I just tried to and thats the response I got.

Comment: This is hideously annoying.  I asked a question and got the right answer almost immediately.  Why do I have to wait?  Besides, you can always change the accepted answer later.

Comment: @marathon I've seen a few cases where people had accepted answers straight-away, *thinking* that they got the right answer, but which turned out to be incorrect (or of fairly low quality). Sometimes the asker doesn't have the expertise to tell whether an answer just sounds right or is actually right. Other answers can come later from more expert users. Very few technical questions can be asked, answered and tested (just to check it works) within 5 minutes or so. I think it's actually better practice to wait longer (1 or 2 days) to give a chance for others to provide answers too.

Answer (score 7):

Because I wrote an answer that took 14 minutes today and while I was writing, a person who posted a 2 liner got accepted.

While this scenario was completely unavoidable, consider people who do only take a minute to write the answer, and if someone else who posts within 20 seconds is accepted it might deter people.

I kind of feel a little robbed personally... [Should I use a physical page for a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254864/should-i-use-a-physical-page-for-a-list/7255104#7255104)

But if it was shorter... it would be even more annoying!

Answer (score 2):

I have no insight into this, but here's another possibility:

My friend and I have accounts on Stack Overflow. We make an agreement to increase each others' rep and get badges by answering each others' questions. So we try to ask and answer as many questions as possible, as fast as possible.

By limiting how soon an answer can be accepted, the system prevents us from artificially boosting our rep too quickly.

### Disclaimer:

Hopefully it goes without saying that this is just a hypothetical, I have never done this nor have any plans to do so.

Comment: Might want to clarify that this is a hypothetical, not your actual dastardly plan.

Comment: Dangit Jimmy, now everybody knows what you and I were planning. Also, come to my office, and bring donuts. And a flux capacitor. Back on the good ole 27th floor.

Comment: @mmyers Of course

Comment: @jcolebrand That's what I get for posting!