# Why do I need to wait for certain amount of time before selecting an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does StackOverflow make you wait 2-x minutes before you can accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85521/why-does-stackoverflow-make-you-wait-2-x-minutes-before-you-can-accept-an-answer)

I am kind of new to SO. Initially, when I was posting some questions, to which answers came ridiculously fast, not sure, how they did that. But, I wanted to accept the solution, and then it said You have to wait 10 more minutes or something like that.

Then, I waited, then another solution came to the page posted by another super-user. But, looked like he paid a lot of attention to detail in posting the answer/reply/solution.

The first one solved my question and I felt that since the first user answered first, I selected his answer, But, I feel bad for the super-user who took so much of his valuable time to post the solution to the answer. I felt like if I can select the answer right away, I didn't have to feel bad and think about who posted the fastest solution or best solution. Am I the only one with this dilemma?

Comment: First off, you can upvote as many answers as you want. You should accept the answer that you feel best helped you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does StackOverflow make you wait 2-x minutes before you can accept an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85521/why-does-stackoverflow-make-you-wait-2-x-minutes-before-you-can-accept-an-answer) Also see [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47448/allow-me-to-accept-an-answer-immediately) proposing that the current system change, and [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-post), which added the wait time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking here, but I will try to answer the different points.

The reason there is a time limit is to ensure that more answers can be considered, as there can be other, more considered and thoughtful answers coming after the first ones. See [Solving the "Fastest gun in the west" problem](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/solving-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem/) for details about this.

As for who you should select - you should select the answer that best helped you with your question. Not the fastest one, not the longest one, not the most researched one - the one that helped you most.

You can always upvote all the answers that you feel deserve it.

Answer (score 5):

That dilemma is the point of the wait. People should have the chance to post a better answer than the others for a while, so you can then choose the *best* answer to accept.

Answer (score 4):

It's to give everyone a chance to post a better answer than this one. :-P