# Why do I have to wait some time before accepting an answer?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does StackOverflow make you wait 2-x minutes before you can accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85521/why-does-stackoverflow-make-you-wait-2-x-minutes-before-you-can-accept-an-answer)

I asked a question and a person answered it. Now if I try to accept it the system asks me to wait as illustrated by the image below:

[image]

Why is this so?

Comment: To prevent abuse, there's a wait time.

Comment: And What sort of abuse is this..???

Comment: Rewarding the fastest answerer even if it may not be the best answer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47448/allow-me-to-accept-an-answer-immediately and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-post

Comment: Related: [Allow me to accept an answer immediately](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47448/131713), [Why can't I accept an answer immediately?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135083/131713), [What's the purpose of “You can accept an answer in N seconds” hint?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56996/131713) and [Jeff's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44099/131713) to [Discourage questions being marked as answered within an hour or so of being posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38090/131713).

Comment: @Lix The message box doesn't say **why**, which was the subject of this question.

Comment: @aaronBertrand Sir And what if answer completely fulfils what you want..?? still cant accept..

Comment: @AlphaMale no offense, but if the very first answer completely fulfills what you want, a very simple search may have yielded an answer even faster. Someone took time out of their day to read your search query, provide an answer, you can wait 15 minutes to check the box.

Comment: I find it ironic that you waited almost four months to accept the only answer. :-)

Comment: I haven't been to meta... Thats why..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a minimum time that must pass before accepting an answer. See this question:

[Why does StackOverflow make you wait 2-x minutes before you can accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85521/why-does-stackoverflow-make-you-wait-2-x-minutes-before-you-can-accept-an-answer)

Comment: To be accepted in 11, 10, 9...